# Why does the timezone of the server affect MySQL reading of FROM_UNIXTIME epochs?

Tags: mysql, datetime, epoch

I thought that if you passed MySQL an Epoch timestamp (as a long) and used `FROM_UNIXTIME()` to get it as a comparable date, that the timezone of the server wouldn't matter. But it does (at least in our setup - do we need a specific configuration?).

Using MySQL Version: *mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.48-37.8, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1*

I start with my server set to UTC.

When I run a query such as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders
WHERE startTime BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1486509895) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1486596296);
```

I get 127 orders.

I then switch my timezone to be EST:

```
sudo mv /etc/localtime /etc/localtime.bak
sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime
sudo service mysql3306 restart
```

I then run the query again, and this time I get 196 orders!

Why does my server's timezone affect it? Epochs should not be affected by that.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation for `FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) clearly states that:

> Returns a representation of the unix_timestamp argument as a value in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` or `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context. **The value is expressed in the current time zone.** unix_timestamp is an internal timestamp value such as is produced by the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function.

This is why I strongly recommend you run your server in UTC and do any conversions in your application or by specifying an offset for your queries.

Epoch times (e.g. UNIX `time_t`) are expressed in UTC but are *always* rendered in local time if you have a time-zone specified in your environment, be it MySQL or otherwise. The raw numerical value doesn't change depending on your time-zone, in fact it has no concept of a time-zone at all, but converting that to a string in `YYYY-MM-DD` format absolutely requires a time-zone to render anything meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the time zone matters. `FROM_UNIXTIME()` converts an instant in time to a date/time representation. But a given instant can represent a different date or time depending on the time zone. As the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) explicitly states:

> The value is expressed in the current time zone.